# Passport always returning false with isAuthenticated()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I know this may be a duplicate but I'm having no luck with the answers im finding anywhere. isAuthenticated is always returning error no matter what route I am using the middleware on. Here is a part of my server code:

```
const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const path = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const indexRouter = require("./routes/user");
const productRouter = require("./routes/product");
const orderRouter = require("./routes/order");
var cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

dotenv.config();

// require("./middleware/passport")(passport);
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  require("./middleware/passport")(passport)

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECT,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
  },
  () => {
    console.log("connected to db");
  }
);
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.EXPRESS_SESSION,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 20000000000, secure: false },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

My auth middleware:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/User");

// middleware function to add to routes you wanna protect

// ensure authentication
// this is your middleware
module.exports = {
  
  ensureAuthenticated: function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log("auth");
      return next();
    }
    console.log("error");
    res.redirect("back");
  }
}
```

My passport config code:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");


// we're going to pass in passport from app.js
module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    // using email as the username
    // done is like next
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
      },
      (email, password, done) => {
        // check if there is a user with the email. match user
        User.findOne({
          email: email,
        })
          .then((user) => {
            // will either give us the user or null
            if (!user) {
              // null is the error, then user and options
              return done(null, false, {
                message: "email not registered",
              });
            }
            // if it is here then keep going

            // match the password
            // user.password is from the db
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              // if this is true then its assed
              if (isMatch) {
                // null just means no error
                return done(null, user);
              } else {
                return done(null, false, {
                  message: "password incorrect",
                });
              }
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
    )
  );

  // serialising the user and deserialing, still in the exports
  // sessions are established but maintained in the users browser. will not contain credentials but rather the unique cookie

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });
  // return user with new id, then check the id
  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

And finally an example route I am trying to keep protected:

```
router.get("/cart", ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {

    var fullCart = []

    const user = await User.findById({
        _id: req.session.passport.user
    })

    const isAdmin = user.isAdmin
    // console.log(user['cart'])
    const cart = user['cart']
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        var product = await Product.findById({
            _id: cart[i]
        })

        fullCart.push(product)
    }
    // console.log(fullCart)
    res.render( {
        cart: fullCart,
        isAuth: true,
        isAdmin: isAdmin
    })

})
```

I am building this project in React. Initially I did it just using node node and EJS, and it worked. For some reason I can't get it to work now. I have done alot of tinkering with it and still the only way it works is if I remove the ensureAuthenticated middleware.

Any advice for a fairly novice react developer?

Comment: Just to clarify which route are you testing on?
Are you sending back secret token back to server when calling the route

Comment: No I am just storing it in a cookie on the browser at the moment. It serves me alright for the moment as it is a uni project and I am planning to update it in the future. Also I am just trying to get it working on the cart route as I posted, when I get it working here I am planning to implement it to other routes